# How to serialize a list of data in ManyToMany relantionship in Django RESTful API and properly create nested objects?

Tags: python, django, rest, serialization, many-to-many

I think it's a silly question but for few days I cann't handle with it... I've got a two models: Book and Authors. Book can have many Authors, and Authors can have many Book(s). I'm POST-ing a new Book, and i'm passing a "title" and a list of Authors (restful API demands from me passing a list of dictionaries like in example below). I want to create new Authors from this list but wihout overwriting the old ones and without duplicating them.

models.py:

```
class Authors(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=False, null=False)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Authors)
```

serielizers.py:

```
class AuthorsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Authors
        fields = '__all__'

class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    authors = AuthorsSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'authors']
        depth = 1

    def create(self, validated_data):
        authors_data = validated_data.pop('authors')
        book = Book.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for autor in authors_data:
            Authors.objects.create(book=book, **autor)
        return book
```

views.py:

```
class BooksList(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Book.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BookSerializer
```

urls.py:

```
book_list = BooksList.as_view({
    'get': 'list',
    'post': 'create',
})

book_detail = BookDetails.as_view({
    'get': 'retrieve',
    'put': 'update',
    'patch': 'partial_update',
    'delete': 'destroy'})

authors_list = AuthorsList.as_view({
    'get': 'list',
    'post': 'create'})


urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns([
    path('books/', book_list, name='book_list'),
    path('books/<int:pk>', book_detail, name='book_detail'),
    path('authors/', authors_list, name='authors_list'),
])
```

When I'm POST-ing a new object in webrowser in RESTful API like this:

```
{
    "title": "Anything",
    "authors": [{"name":"First Guy"},{"name":"Second Guy"}],
}
```

a'm receiving a new Book object, and two Authors in database, but they are NOT related. I get answer like this:

```
HTTP 201 Created
Allow: GET, POST, PUT, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "id": 8,
    "title": "Anything",
    "authors": [],
}
```

When i'm GET list of Authors they are there like this:

```
   {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "First Guy"
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "name": "Second Guy"
    }
]
```

the view I want to receive is:

```
{
"title": "Anyting",
"authors": [
          "First Guy",
          "Second Guy"
        ]
}
```

Why they are not related and I don't see them in book.authors? Am I requesting GET-method wrong? When i'm doing this throught the admin-panel I can connect "Authors" with "Book" and it works by this way, but ofcourse it should be working through API calls. I've tried dozens of configurations, combinations of brackets, other kind of relations, different arguments, read many od articles/documentations/youtube etc and I can not sleep because of this... And because I'm stucked, I still haven't get to the "update-method", so it would be nice if somebody could explain both of it. Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `create` method in `BookSerializer`. Many-to-Many related objects cannot be assigned directly when creating an instance, i.e. `Authors.objects.create(book=book, **autor)`.

In order to associate an `Author` object with `Book`, you need to do it like:

```py
def create(self, validated_data):
    authors_data = validated_data.pop('authors')
    book = Book.objects.create(**validated_data)
    for autor in authors_data:
        author_instance = Authors.objects.create(**autor)
        book.authors.add(author_instance)
        # or author_instance.book_set.add(book)
    return book
```

Comment: ooo thanks - now the list with Author(s) is connected with Book, but when an Author is in the data base it's duplacating him. Should I use some kind of "if" statement?

Comment: @noumen you will have to identify the incoming author somehow, possible solution would be to send an `id` in your request body and check for existence of that author in the DB. However, I would suggest you not creating an `Author` object, but sending id-s of existing authors and setting them to books